# SQL Warn before a date comes

Tags: sql-server, date, triggers

I have 2 columns which are 'Name' and 'PayDay'.'Payday' is a date type and 'Name' is a nvarchar. I wonder can I get an email of person's name 2 days before of his/her payday comes. For example 'Name' is John and 'Payday' is 12.5.2015. I need to get an email which inlcudes the name 'John' in 10.5.2015. I made a research and find that trigger is a good choice for this. I can take any advice for trigger and also for mail service. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure for what concerns triggers ... they are triggered only when you modify (INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE) data

Comment: You should setup an agent job to query the table everyday at a given time and email names that have payday two days later

Answer (score 2):

We have a similar situation, where by we warn of percentage progress before an expected completion date. I don't think triggers are going to be quite the solution you're looking for.

In our case I developed a simple stored proc to read all table values where completion is expected in x days. I then used this select and concatenated the results into a parameter. If this had a length of greater than 0, then I sent the email.

The code for emailing I use is:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
@profile_name='SQLMail',                          -- Your email profile name here
@recipients'email1@domain.com;email2@domain.com;',-- Recipients emails
@subject='Projects nearing completion',           -- Subject line
@body=@myEmailContent                             -- String built above
```

There are plenty of good guides on emailing out there including all the setup.

To execute this, I ran it from the SQL server agent and just scheduled it to run after midnight. This means I always come into a fresh email, but I only have one email a day.  If you try and run this from a trigger, you'd get an email every time the table is written to.

If you have any further questions on this drop me a message and I'll see what I can do to help.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
    Name NVARCHAR(50),
    PayDay DATE
)

INSERT INTO @t (Name, PayDay)
VALUES (N'Jonh 1', '20151203'), (N'Jonh 2', '20151201')

DECLARE @date DATE = DATEADD(DAY, 2, GETDATE())

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @t WHERE PayDay = @date) BEGIN

    DECLARE @recipients NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @recipients = STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + Name
        FROM @t
        WHERE PayDay = @date
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @date) + ':')

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @recipients = 'your_account@gmail.com',
        @subject = 'caption',
        @body = @recipients

END
```

database mail + daily job in sql agent + code above